# How to get the name's value from a input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the name's value from an input HTML element using jQuery but it doesn't works.

**HTML** code:

> ```
> <p class="myclass"><input type="text" name="thisismyname1" value="123"></p>
> <p class="myclass"><input type="text" name="thisismyname2" value="456"></p>
> <p class="myclass"><input type="text" name="thisismyname3" value="789"></p>
> ```

I am trying to get all the name values using this peace of code in **jQuery**:

> ```
> $(.myclass).each(function(value){
>   alert('input name='+ $(this).attr('name') +'='+$(this).val());
>   });
> ```

This `$(this).attr('name')` seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for the input under the context of each iteration, like below,

```
$(".myclass").each(function() {

  var $input = $(this).find("input");
  alert ("Name: " + $input.attr("name"));
  alert ("Value: " + $input.val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You search by ***p*** but ***p*** does not have attribute name, your selector should like this

```
$('.myclass input').each(function(value){
  console.log('input name='+ $(this).attr('name') +'='+$(this).val());
});
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/jujaho/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/jujaho/2/edit?html,js,console)